# Spring Boot POST parameter size limit

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, openresty

I seem to be butting heads with a limiter somewhere. One of my Spring-Boot REST endpoint (POST) parameters (`surveyResults`) is looking for a string of JSON:

```
    private static final String SURVEY_RESULTS_ENDPOINT = "/survey/results";

    @PostMapping(
        value = SURVEY_RESULTS_ENDPOINT, 
        produces = { "application/hal+json", "application/json" }
    )   
    @ApiOperation(value = "Save one survey results")
    public Resource<SurveyResult> createSurveyResults(

            @ApiParam(value = "who/what process created this record", required = true) @Valid 
                @RequestParam(value = "recordCreatedBy", required = true) String createdBy,

            @ApiParam(value = "was an issue identified", required = true) 
                @RequestParam(value = "hadFailure", required = true) Boolean hadFailure,

            @ApiParam(value = "JSON representation of the results", required = true) 
                @RequestParam(value = "surveyResults", required = true) String surveyResult

    ) ...
```

If I post to this with about 1500 characters, it works. Somewhere just over that and it will fail with a HTTP `400` error [bad request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors). The whole payload is less than 2K with the other parameters.

I just moved from Wildfly to a new server setup. My company is adopting continuous deployment to cloud servers so i don't have much control nor visibility to this new load balanced server. The server is `"server": "openresty/1.13.6.2"` - any idea what limit I am running into?

Comment: That what you have given is not a `post` method. Can you share the method completely, with all annotations and body?

Comment: Do you send data in querystring (results parameter) to a post method, just like a get operation? If so there will be a size limit regarding to max querystring limit

Comment: @aksappy - I'm using `@PostMapping` - more code now present. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.

`@RequestBody` annotation maps the HTTP request's body to an object. `@RequestParam` maps the request parameter in the request, which is in the URL and not in the body.

Most browsers have a limitation to the number of characters supported in a request parameter, and you just hit that limit.

What I would suggest is to create a POJO that looks like this

```
public class Body {
   private String createdBy; 
   private Boolean hadFailure;  
   private String surveyResult;

// getters and setters
}
```

Now your controller will be simpler

```
@PostMapping(
        value = SURVEY_RESULTS_ENDPOINT, 
        produces = { "application/hal+json", "application/json" }
    )   
public Resource<SurveyResult> createSurveyResults(@RequestBody Body body) {

}
```

Wherever you are posting, you will have to now post a JSON (`Content-Type = application/json`) that looks like the following

```
{ "createdBy" : "foo", "hadFailure" : false, "surveyResult" : "the foo bar"}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Swagger is using a GET because I did this isn't it.

Comment: Swagger must be performing a post (that is governed by `@PostMapping`), but since you have mapped the parameters to `@RequestParam` it is appending everything to the URL.

Comment: I have a spring boot application which serves a DELTE request to delete one or more elements & accepts object IDs as part of query parameter. I want to know if a ID is of length 20 chars(just an example) is there a limitation to call this API from another API without any limit on length considering browsers are not involved? if there's any limitation, what's the length? I tried to find in spring boot docs but could not find it.