# Sending Large JSON with multiple input Input Files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, postman

I am trying to upload few files with a large JSON Body ,

Previously (when there was no file uploading) , I was using `@RequestBody` for JSON which automatically parse my request into Object just like below.

```
@PostMapping("/TestEndPoint")
public void uploadData(@RequestBody MyClass jsonBody ) 
{

myService.uploadData(jsonBody)

}
```

But now since I am trying to implement upload function , I found that file and JSON can be send through `@RequestParameter` but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58886648/7231831)  , It's not a good idea to send Large JSON in the @RequestParam as it appends it with URL .

Here is what I am trying to do ,

```
@PostMapping("/TestEndPoint")
public void uploadData(@RequestBody MyClass jsonBody , @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) 
{

myService.uploadData(jsonBody)

}
```

I've read that you have to either pass request body or request parameters ( in body) , if it is correct what is an alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could just send the JSON also as a request parameter, which should be quite straightforward. In the controller you then manually convert it to your transport object.

```
@PostMapping("/TestEndPoint")
public void uploadData(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file1, 
    @RequestParam("jsonFile") MultipartFile file2) throws IOException {

    String objString = new String(file2.getBytes());
    MyClass jsonBody = new ObjectMapper().readValue(objString, MyClass.class);        
    myService.uploadData(jsonBody);
}
```

The client who is sending the request just has to convert the JSON into bytes and add it to the request as a request parameter. I have not tested the code, but it should work like this I guess.

Comment: could be an alternative , but require a few modifications in client side  as well as for server side.